# Sitecore Axes.IsDescendantOf / Axes.IsAncestorOf - Inclusive?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, items

Is there a reason or something that I am missing that has Sitecore return `true` for both `Item.Axes.IsDescendantOf()` and `Item.Axes.IsAncestorOf()`?

```
var test =
Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("{862B466A-079B-40E7-8661-FC064EC28574}");  
Response.Write(test.Axes.IsAncestorOf(test));  
Response.Write(test.Axes.IsDes(test));
```

> //True
>   //True

**Edit**: Anyone whom may stumble across this answer looking for non-inclusive `IsAncestorOf` or `IsDescendantOf`, below are a couple examples where I need to find the highest level elements in a multi-select field for news categories.

```
newsCategories
   .Where(x => newsCategories
                       .Any(y => x != y && !x.Axes.IsDescendantOf(y)))
```

and

```
newsCategories
   .Where(x => newsCategories
                       .Any(y => x != y && !x.Axes.IsDescendantOf(y)))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would have to believe that the methods in Sitecore should **not** be named `IsAncestorOf` and `IsDescendantOf`. Based on your finding, and quickly looking at the Sitecore code, the methods should really be named `IsAncestorOrSelf` and `IsDescendantOrSelf`.

For this example,

```
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item x = //some item;
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item y = //some item;
x.Axes.IsAncestorOf(y)
x.Axes.IsDescendantOf(y)
```

The `IsAncestorOf` method is comparing `x.ID == y.ID`. It will then keep comparing `x.ID` to the `ID` of y's parent, which is why it should be named `IsAncestorOrSelf`.

The `IsDescendantOf` method is comparing if the `LongID` path of `x` starts with the `LongID` path of `y`. Being that a string always starts with the same string we again see that this method should be named `IsDescendantOrSelf`.

FYI, A `LongID` path looks like this `/{11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}/{0DE95AE4-41AB-4D01-9EB0-67441B7C2450}/{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}` and I suspect is used rather than `/sitecore/content/home` in order to get around the fact that sitecore allows siblings to have the same name.

Comment: Sean, answered the question perfectly and I had a feeling this was the case. I noticed a `IsDescendantOrSelf` method somewhere in the source as well.

Comment: For what it's worth, I logged the issue with Sitecore #365788

Comment: Looking at the source (ILSpy) for ItemPath.IsAncestorOf in Sitecore 7.2. It looks like this is fixed. The comparison starts with the parameter's parent item.

What really confused me was the parameter naming: IsAncestorOf(ancestorItem), where ancestorItem is (or isn't) a descendant. Ditto for IsDescendantOf(descendantItem), where descendantItem is (or isn't) an ancestor. Both should just be named 'item'.

Answer (score 2):

You are hitting a "fail safe" in the Sitecore logic. 
It is because you are checking the same item against it self. You need to perform this with 2 different items to produce any result.

Comment: Sandbeck, do you know why it's a failsafe or it's use case? I'm curious of the answer. I noted that they are comparing the IDs of the two items but not checking if they are the same item in the decompiled source.

Comment: How would two items have the same ID but but be the same item? Unless you are somehow factoring in language and/or database.

Comment: `string longID = this._item.Paths.LongID; string str2 = item.Paths.LongID;  return longID.StartsWith(str2);` Apologize if I alluded to the wrong thing.